# MATLAB Functions using Vectors

Tags: function, matlab, vector

I'm attempting to evaluates the function `x -> (e^x - 1) / x` at the following seven values:

```
1, .5, .1, .01, .001, .00001, .0000001
```

My code is:

```
x = [1,.5, .1, .01, .001, .00001, .0000001];
y = (exp(x)-1)/x
```

The issue is that this yields only one value for y, namely:

```
y =
   1.629441654061645
```

I noticed that if I remove /x, it gives me seven values that correspond to each value of x (albeit the wrong ones).

Why is this the case, exactly?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`/` gives you a matrix division, while what you want is an elementwise division. That's done with the `./` operator:

```
 y = (exp(x)-1)./x
```

Comment: That makes a lot of sense... I forget that vectors are technically matrices. Thank you!